# PHPUnit and a singleton

Tags: php, design-patterns, singleton, phpunit, assertions

So I just started to try PHPUnit for the first time on a small framework that I have created. In this framework I have a singleton class. Trying to run a simple test just to verify that I am getting a correct instance its failing and honestly I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Here is my test.

```
class ConfigTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_Testcase
{
    public function TestGettingInstanceOf()
    {
       $conf = Config::getInstance('test.php');
       $this->assert($conf instanceOf Config);
    }
}
```

Comment: Config::getInstance('test'); ???

Comment: I get it... I know... it obvious, still would like to figure the test. I know Im instantiating the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turn out that tests in PHPUnit must start with the word `test` (all lower case) and  I should have used `$this->assertInstanceOf('Config', $conf);`. Therefore my function should have been written like:

```
public function testGettingInstanceOf()
{
   $conf = Config::getInstance('test.php');
   $this->assertInstanceOf('Config', $conf);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can get concept like this.

```
 <?php
class MySingleton
{
    private static $_instance;

    private function __construct(){
        // constructor code here it will be called once only
    }

    public static function init(){
        if(self::$_instance == null){
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;            
    }

    public function someMethod(){
        echo "Doing something!";
    }
}
?>
```

More details about single then read [Singleton Classes in PHP](http://www.apphp.com/tutorials/index.php?page=singleton-classes-in-php)

Comment: The question was not how or what is a Singleton but how to run a simple test for the sake of testing and getting familiar with PHPUnit and this test is for the `getInstance()` function.

Comment: you should be understand visit the link. ok

Comment: Wonder how you get an up vote with such bad answer... blows mi mind?

Comment: i simple example singleton in php not phpUnit, sorry brother, now from i answer depandable for question. sorrry